# How to make 3D Images gallery for 3D Android Devices such as HTC Evo 3D or other 3d Compatible devices?

Tags: android, image, 3d, gallery

I want to create a 3D image gallery for 3D compatible device, But I have no idea how to start and how to test the application . I have one android device SonyEricsson Xperia neo V. Is it possible to test that application with this device ? If no, then how can I create the application and how to test?

Comment: Have you looked at the manufacturers developer website for 3D SDKs?